# Documenting PHP ArrayAccess objects

Tags: php, phpdoc

I have a class Table which exposes some properties via magic `__get()` and also provides array-like access, e.g `$table['col1']` is instance of Column. Compact example:

```php
$table = new Table();
// via magic getter
$table->readonly = false;
// $table['id'] returns Column object
$table['id']->readonly = true;
```

**How can I document array elements to return Column?** I have already doc for magic properties. I've tried to document offsetGet but it does not work, at least in PhpStorm. Example:

```php
/**
 * @property boolean $readonly
 * NOTE offsetGet DOES NOT WORK
 * @method Column offsetGet(string $offset)
 */
class Table implements \ArrayAccess {
}

/**
 * @property boolean $readonly
 */
class Column {
}
```

I know how to document array variable or method return value, but adding such doc to each usage is not exactly what I'm looking for.

```php
/** @var Table|array<string,Column> $table */
$table = new Table;
```

[image]

Edit: Seems the problem was in PhpStorm, it needed restart. Phpdoc for offsetGet() did the trick after all. Case closed.